# AngularJS: Dependency Management

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We are currently planning a website which exists out of different AngularJS apps that will make use of common services. Services will be implemented in seperate files; to minimize the filesize of the apps we want to include/concatenate only those service-files that are used in the corresponding app - so we are looking for the best practise in dependency management.

is there something like requireJS in angular or what would you suggest to handle the includes? 
thanks in advance .)

Comment: Me personally? I'd just use [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) and call it a day.

Comment: Grunt is not a dependency manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use the same organization as ng-boilerplate: 
https://github.com/joshdmiller/ng-boilerplate

I use an organization close to ng-boilerplat for one project and it allowed us to be modular in our dependency management.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the only build/deployment system that works like a charm for most web apps that have extremely js computation is [yeoman](http://yeoman.io).
This quote should describe what it is/does:

> Yeoman 1.0 is more than just a tool. It's a workflow; a collection of tools and best practices working in harmony to make developing for the web even better.

So basically, it is a [npm](https://npmjs.org/) that installs all the boilerplate files, dependencies and configures your whole app with the help of [generators](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular). It uses [bower](http://bower.io/) and [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/)also takes care of the hard part of configuring [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) that is in charge of building/deploying your app.
I highly recommend **[yeoman](http://yeoman.io)** as a **modern** and **efficient** workflow.

Comment: yeoman and angularjs seem to be very common today, but it looks like that the angular-generator focuses on one single app. is it possible to define multiple modules/apps so that the apps can use common services?!

Comment: You could certainly customize your own generators in order to suit your needs, but for individual modules/scripts the common approach is to manage them trough bower. You can (and should!) install/remove/update *packages* (scripts/git repos/modules) in your app using it.

Answer (score 0):

I personally haven't looked at the `ng-boilerplate` as @Julio mentioned above, but you could easily manage to configure and use `RequireJS` with angular of you want to. I've done it and it works like a charm.